# Is this possible to integrate gravity form with multiple payment gateway?

Tags: payment-gateway, gravity-forms-plugin

I have to integrate gravity form with multiple payment gateway.

the first is

1)paypal

and second is

2)authorized.net

so my question is that can i integrate gravity form with multiple payment gateway as i mentioned.

if it is possible so how can i start i mean any guide line?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to integrate Gravity Forms with multiple payment gateways:

1. Obtain the add-on for each of the payment gateways you'd like to integrate with. In your case, you'll need the PayPal Add-On and the Authorize.net Add-On.
2. Install and activate those add-ons
3. Create your form, being sure to add a choice field and use that field in your Gravity Forms conditional logic choosing between the payment gateways. Check out this [example using PayPal and Stripe](https://gravityplus.pro/how-to/setup-multiple-payment-options-on-one-gravity-form/) — it works the same for any payment processor (there's also an example form there that you can import into your site to see how it works directly in the form editor).
4. Follow the instructions for each payment gateway add-on to connect the form to the payment gateways (most commonly you'll create a feed and set a condition on the feed to only trigger if that payment gateway is selected). The [tutorial example](https://gravityplus.pro/how-to/setup-multiple-payment-options-on-one-gravity-form/) has screenshots of how this looks.

Comment: i will try this i am really appreciate your answer

Comment: is this possible with pay by group payment gateway and paypal payment gateway to integrate gravity form with multiple payment gateway.?

Comment: @SanjayNakate I've not encountered the 'pay by group' payment gateway, but I do know that this will work with any of the payment gateways that are developed in the standard manner of creating a feed or a rule to connect the form to the gateway. So, the PayPal and Authorize.net gateways you mention in your question will work.